# Android ParseException getCode() returning -1

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform

I'm trying to validate a sign up using Parse. Normally the sign up works but I'm trying to incorporate some error checks. When printing the ParseException to the logs as Log.d("Error",""+e); I get the error message.

But when I use e.getCode() instead, I don't get the error code displayed. It's -1 always.

```
                parseUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        registerProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (e == null) {
                            // No error

                            goToProfileActivity(getActivity(), false);
                        } else {

                            Log.d("Error", "" + e);
                            signupErrorHandler(e.getCode());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you try with e.getMessage(); ?

Comment: Normally using just e or e.getMessage() gives me the error messages just fine. I need the error code to handle it. But it always returns -1